# Struggling to loop through an array of objects

Tags: javascript

in particular I want to access answer's numerical value, so that later on to sum them up.

previously tried length, which is not working for objects.

here is my data:

```
const qData = [
    {
        id: 0,
        question: "question 1",
        answers: [
            { value: 1, text: "rafael" },
            { value: 2, text: "dontaelo" },
            { value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
            { value: 4, text: "michelangelo" }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        question: "question 2",
        answers: [
            { value: 1, text: "rafael" },
            { value: 2, text: "dontaelo" },
            { value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
            { value: 4, text: "michelangelo" }
        ]
    }
];

export default qData;
```

I attempted to sum the answer values like so:

```
handleShowScore = () => {
  var i, newScore;
  var a = qData.answers;

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    newScore = newScore + a[i].value;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no JSON in the code shown here. JSON is a text format, and `qData` is an array of objects.

Comment: `qData.forEach(p => console.log(p.answers))` will print all answers

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: thanks. changed to array of objects. checking the answer

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving this yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties

Comment: Sure. As i said  my previous attempt was through length which is not working  handleShowScore = () => {
  var i, newScore;
  var a = qData.answers;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   newScore = newScore + a[i].value;
  }

Comment: Your approach goes wrong because `qData.answers` does not exist. It must be `qData[0].answers` or another number.

Comment: Why do you want to sum all the answer values?? And what does this have to do with ReactJS?

Comment: part of the quiz in reactjs

Comment: OK, but in the context of this question there is no ReactJS. But surely you don't want to sum all the numeric values of each question to calculate a score?

Comment: re scores - that is correct assumption. And you are right of course, taking out reactjs tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qData` is an array and doesn't have the property `answers`, so `qData.answers` will not work and return `undefined`.

You first have to loop over the questions, then in each question you'll have to loop over the answers:

```js
const qData = [{id:0,question:"question 1",answers:[{value:1,text:"rafael"},{value:2,text:"dontaelo"},{value:3,text:"leonardo"},{value:4,text:"michelangelo"}]},{id:1,question:"question 2",answers:[{value:1,text:"rafael"},{value:2,text:"dontaelo"},{value:3,text:"leonardo"},{value:4,text:"michelangelo"}]}];

let sum = 0;
for (const question of qData) {
  for (const answer of question.answers) {
    sum += answer.value;
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

You could do this reduce the amount of loops if you use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Pulling up the answers into one large array.

```js
const qData = [{id:0,question:"question 1",answers:[{value:1,text:"rafael"},{value:2,text:"dontaelo"},{value:3,text:"leonardo"},{value:4,text:"michelangelo"}]},{id:1,question:"question 2",answers:[{value:1,text:"rafael"},{value:2,text:"dontaelo"},{value:3,text:"leonardo"},{value:4,text:"michelangelo"}]}];

const answers = qData.flatMap(question => question.answers);

let sum = 0;
for (const answer of answers) {
  sum += answer.value;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Instead of using a for loop to sum the values you could also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which iterates over an array reducing it to a single value.

```js
const qData = [{id:0,question:"question 1",answers:[{value:1,text:"rafael"},{value:2,text:"dontaelo"},{value:3,text:"leonardo"},{value:4,text:"michelangelo"}]},{id:1,question:"question 2",answers:[{value:1,text:"rafael"},{value:2,text:"dontaelo"},{value:3,text:"leonardo"},{value:4,text:"michelangelo"}]}];

const answers = qData.flatMap(question => question.answers);
const sum = answers.reduce((sum, answer) => sum + answer.value, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thank you for taking time and answering my question! it worked perfectly. I just tailored for my particular problem.                                                                                                                               handleShowScore = () => {
  const answers = document.querySelectorAll("select");
  let newScore = 0;
  for (const answer of answers) {
   newScore = newScore + parseInt(answer.value, 10);
  }

  this.setState({
   score: newScore
  });
 };

Answer (score 0):

The sample below does what you want, if I understood your question correctly

```
// Loop through all questions. Each question is stored in "q".
qData.forEach((q) => {
  console.log('qData:', q);
​
  // Make an array of all answer values   
  const answerValues = q.answers.map((a) => {
     return a.value;
  });
  console.log('answerValues:', answerValues);
​
  // Sum all answer values together
  const totalValues = answerValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  console.log('totalValues: ', totalValues);
});
```

If you want to have the sum of a specific ID

```js
// Find specific ID.
const question = qData.find((q) => q.id === 0);

// Make an array of all answer values   
const answerValues = question.answers.map((a) => {
   return a.value;
});
console.log('answerValues:', answerValues);

// Sum all answer values together
const totalValues = answerValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
console.log('totalValues: ', totalValues);
```

Comment: thanks Joel for answering my question! Solution from 3limin4t0r suits better to my particular problem. have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a quiz, right? Let's assume my answers are:

```
const myAnswers = [{question: 'question 1', myAnswer:'rafael'},{question: 'question 2', myAnswer:'dontaelo'}]
```

I should have 1 point from the first question, and 2 from the second. We need to go through 2 loops: 1 to find the corresponding question, 1 to find the corresponding number of points:

```
const myPoints = myAnswers.map(answer => qData.find(question => question.question === answer.question).answers.find(possibleAnswer => possibleAnswer.text === answer.myAnswer).value)
```

Thats gives me [ 1, 2 ]. Now we need to to the sum with reduce:

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
const myScore = myPoints.reduce(reducer, 0);
```

I have 3 points ;-)

Comment: thank you Fabien for taking time and answering my question! I found solution from 3limin4t0r more suitable to my particular problem. have a great day!

Comment: Glad you found your answer